# IndexOf Method VB.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I use the Indexof Method to search for an Index a number?  The number will be different on each line of the file.   Each array has a name and a different zip code.  I want to tell it to search for the first number in the line.  Everything before that index will be first name, last name, and then zip code.

```
infile = IO.File.OpenText("Names.txt")

    'process the loop instruct until end of file
    intSubscript = 0
    Do Until infile.Peek = -1
        'read a line
        strLine(intSubscript) = infile.ReadLine
        intSubscript = intSubscript + 1


    Loop

    infile.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution from how I understand this:

Instead of using the IndexOf, you can save each part of the file on a different line (ReadLine).

If you really need the IndexOf: It's just `String.IndexOf(EnterCharacterHere)`

You could also read this file and only use the numbers found:

First you make a const string `const cstrNumbers as string = "0123456789"` and then do the following:

```
For x as integer = 0 to strInput -1
    strTemporary = strInput.Substring(x,1)
    If InStr(cstrNumbers, strTemporary) <> 0 Then
         strOutput &= strTemporary
```

strOutput will contain the numbers then.

Hope this helps,

Simon

EDIT:
This would be easier with a database, but I have no experience with db in vb.net.

You could do a substring combined with the InStr I mentioned.

First you need a function that will return the first occurrence of a number. (With InStr)

And then use this in the substring `(String.SubString(FirstOccurence, LengthOfZip)`

Don't have the time to do the complete code now..Hope this helps you a bit

Comment: I can't do that because it will change.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Do the text files change?

Comment: The text files don't change, but there are 10 separate lines.  The user enters first name and last name in separate text boxes.  The files is First name, then last name then zip code in each row.  I want to tell it to look for the first digit of the zip code and assign everything before that to a name variable to compare it to the user input and look for a match, then display the zip.